# my vuex store doesn't update my file in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

this is my store, why do i keep getting products object even when it's not in my store

[image]

this my order.js code

```
import axios from "axios";
const state = {
  orders: [],

};
const mutations = {
  SET_ORDERS(state, orders) {
    state.orders = orders;
  },

};
const actions = {
  async fetchOrders({
    commit
  }) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/orders"
      );
      let orders = response.data.products;
      commit('SET_ORDERS', orders);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching orders:", error);
    }
  },

};
const getters = {
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

why do i keep getting products [] when its not in my store

i've tried refreshing my store ,npm  run serve but no avail

Comment: You don't have another store define?
Try a hard reset of everything, newtork inspector, inside application, delete session storage, local storage, cookies, cache.

Comment: @RaphaelRlt i have other store but this store is just for orders but keeps displaying  product

Comment: like @dbzx10299 say, have you check your store in real? Login the store directly, maybe it's just the plugin devtools.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue before, I had to close chrome devtools, refresh the page and reopen them. The vue devtools don‘t always update when the refresh icon is clicked from within.